# What is the reason of getting empty report with jdbc datasource?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using `iReport  4.7.0`. To get report in table format I am connecting to *`SQL Server 2005`*.

I am creating a dataset while designing a table that gives me a field values which are in database table but after complete design while I am previewing my *`jrxml`* file it doesn't show me a table with values.

I want to know what is the problem.

My *`jrxml`* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="09817b9b-055f-4d9f-b22e-85b7fac3d81e" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="35"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="9bfe7683-aa43-4113-b4a6-8007d4c7ff5d">
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select * from employee]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="first_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="last_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="salary" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <group name="id">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
        <group name="first_name">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{first_name}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
        <group name="last_name">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{last_name}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3f6a40c5-cb7c-4237-8635-19aab55cef63" x="205" y="16" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Test Database]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="6dc5bcfb-b281-4ec4-a611-4e5b602031ed" key="table" style="table" x="16" y="10" width="527" height="115"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="ba8de9b8-6e5b-4178-a62d-380ec6e268c2">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column uuid="8a09f431-ce9d-4c86-bde8-b6eba830a10f" width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="05cb64bd-b18c-4323-9365-ed6fa5d763ae" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[id]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="31" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="2fb15323-2f8b-4234-ae0b-7272676180df" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="db3eb7e3-b13d-4dff-b4cf-c64aa06853f2" width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="d60ed209-0e4f-4e66-8a4b-53a117a4fdf2" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[first_name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="31" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="4dc05d21-5b86-4da2-b64f-9f83666e1948" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{first_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="1bdd10f7-b718-4fbc-9fca-9f0a7883dc5c" width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="2bdbbd7d-f990-4261-9243-6b0f9f7feb7b" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[last_name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="31" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="d361d452-b63c-47ff-a2de-33b3f6bebe9c" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{last_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="da448dd2-72b0-4e70-92f8-0343fa894cc0" width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="388b140a-53d8-4097-b483-007767ab3494" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[salary]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="31" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="25c5ca88-39e2-4ea2-abd7-d1afe2df4ed9" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{salary}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="e22bf754-66e2-4993-9e24-93ef1cfadaaa" x="0" y="44" width="555" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="94fcb4b3-e6da-4603-a6f1-f10063aee62e" x="409" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What does it show you? Can you post your JRXML file?

Comment: it shows me any other design part which i designed in jrxml file but it doesn't show data from database

Comment: i will give you my jrxml file

Comment: i also attached image of my jrxml design file

Comment: can u tell me how to post my coding file here

Comment: now my problem is solved but it shows data 3 times and if i preview it in adobe reader it shows me in 4 pages 7 times same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your *Detail* band is not printed (your report's property ***When No Data***  has **All Sections, No Detail** value) because your main dataset is empty (I did not find in your template any others datasets except the ***New Dataset 1*** subdataset).

You can move (put) your *Table* component to the *Title* band, for example.

---

You can find the sample of using *Table* component [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/table/index.html#table).

Comment: if i put Table componennt to title band it throws some saxper Exception

Comment: thanks for giving some suggestion

Comment: What exception? It is a normal way to put *Table* component to the *Title* band.

Comment: When did you get it (during compilation, during saving, during execution, ...)? What description?

Comment: if i am developing struts2 web application and i am compiling jrxml file through java program means in action class and i am passing some parameters through that java program and also accesing some fields of bean class through javabean set datasource in ireport at that time how will i set javabean set datasource in dataset to show field values in table which we are accesing through javabean set datasource

Comment: You can use [JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReportToFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29) method. You can look at [this sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)

Comment: thanks once again now i am going to try it

Comment: i am creating struts2 web project.In that project i am using ireport 4.7.0 for designing report and i am giving a classpath of my project to get the data from java program till this it runs successful it also get the fields from java program. But while i am designing a table to get my data which i am taking from java program i can't get the fields in dataset. How to get fields from java program in dataset while designing a table format report?